# What does "for letter in greeting" do in the given code?

Tags: python-3.x

```
greeting = 'Hello!'
count = 0
for letter in greeting:
    count += 1
    if count % 2 == 0:
        print(letter)
    print(letter)
print('done')
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: And [read the excellent Python documentation!](http://docs.python.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Python are sequences of individual characters, so what `for letter in greeting` does is to iterate through each character in the string `greeting`, and assign each character to the variable `letter` in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer will be :
!
!
done

Detailed Explanation :-

Your string is greeting='Hello!'
You have initialized Count to 0
In line, " for letter in greeting: " --> letter is not a property of for loop but simply a variable that will hold each alphabet of string in incrementing iterations. You can also use --> for i in greeting:  --> then 'i' will contain each alphabet of string stored in variable 'greeting'.
Then Count+=1 , will execute for all letters in string "Hello!" i.e H,e,l,l,o,!  --> Count = 6.
Then it will check that if Count is divisible by 2 or "is an even number" then it will display "letter" i.e. '!' because after complete execution of above 'for loop' the last value in variable letter is '!'. Since, if statement results in true, it will print '!' followed by '!' and finally 'done'.